# react-native android error Failed to install the app native_modules.gradle' line: 170

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, react-native

running react-native run-android in windows but get this error:

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>   Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>   :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running 'npx --quiet --no-install react-native config' command from 'null' directory.
>   :ReactNative:Running 'npx --quiet --no-install react-native config' command from 'null' directory failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 170
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Command `config` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Comment: did you properly setup `Android development environment setup` ?
if no then do it first.
you can see the step here:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: hi, tanks for comment, but  I did it before

Comment: you can try this,

make `local.properties` file in your project `android` dir.
and add your android-sdk path into that.
like `sdk.dir=/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: already, by using search in **stackoverflow**,  tried this solution, but not working   :(
code is 
`sdk.dir = C:\Users\shafiei.mi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Answer (score 24):

Try running (inside android folder)

```
 ./gradlew clean
```

and then run

```
 react-native run-android
```

Comment: This command worked for me, also notice it the project was initially created in window so gradlew was not having enough permissions to run on linux

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: I did this _and_ updated the node version. Not sure if the latter was required, but did it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurred when I was using the latest react-native package "0.61.5" ... I solved it by performing some steps

- Removed node_modules
- Install npm

> npm install npm 
>     or 
>   npm install npm@latest

- And Install react-native

> npm install --save react-native

Answer (score 4):

Add this to gradle.properties:

> `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip`

and add this to gradle.wrapper.properties:

> `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip`

then run react-native run-android

Comment: This worked! But does that mean that we would have to make these changes every time we initialize a react-native project? Is there some other way?

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurred when i was using latest react native package "0.61.5" ...
I solved it by changing react native package to "0.61.4"

Go to **package.json** file
change the version of react native

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4"
 }
```

and do

```
npm install
```

Comment: thank you for answer, i did this solution, but It was not successful for install app

Answer (score -4):

Simply install yarn by the command

```
yarn install
```

This happens when you pull code from the repository having npm installed libararies and you are running by yarn